# dovecot: %d is empty for pre auth local users

Tags: domain, dovecot

I have configured:

```
mail_location = maildir:/var/mail/%d/%n
```

(%d is the domain part of user@domain.com)

This works fine for remote users, but a local user running

```
/usr/lib/dovecot/imap
```

gets:

> Error: user kiigass: Initialization failed: Namespace '': mkdir(/var/mail//kiigass)

obviously the %d domain is empty. I set:

```
auth_default_realm = domain.com
```

but it seems to have no effect on local users. Is there a possibility to set a (default) domain for local users running `/usr/lib/dovecot/imap` ?